# getOne and getAll with local Observables cache and remote database

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a list of 'todos' that will change throughout and between a user sessions and are displayed to the user in various components. I want to employ the 'single source of truth' and 'keeping the data in the stream as long as possible' best-practice heuristics without going all the way to using ngrx or similar.

Specifically, I want to create a 1) todos$ observable and 2) individual todo$ observables that are piped from $todos and 3) a getByTodoId function that looks for a todo locally then makes an http call if its not found. I want to be very careful about next -> http -> next loop though.

What I have now:

todoService

```
let todos: Array<todo>;
let todos$: ReplaySubject<Array<todo>>;

getTodoById(id): Observable<todo> => {

    // looks in a todo array
    let todo = todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)

    if (todo) {
      return of(todo);
    }

    return http.post(urlgetTodoById, {id}).pipe(
      map((todo) => {

        todos.push(todo)
        todos$.next(todos)
        return todo;
      })
    );
  }
```

todoComponent

```
localTodo = await getByTodoId.toPromise()
```

What I want:

todoService

```
let todo$; // maybe this should be like ReplaySubject<todo>?

getTodoById = (id) => todos$.pipe(

  a) look id in todos$ and if not found
  b) make api call for specific todo then add to todos$
)
```

todoComponent

```
localTodo$ = todoService.getByTodoId(id)
```

Comment: What's your question? And can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hey Kurt, I made some edits to the question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `BehaviorSubject` to cache, it has a `.getValue()` method which let you get the current value.

```
let todos$=new BehaviorSubject({})

getTodoById = (id) => todos$.pipe(

if(todos$.getValue()[id])
  return todos$.pipe(pluck(id))
else 
  return http.post(urlgetTodoById, {id}).pipe(tap(todo=>
     todo$.next({[id]:todo,...todo$.getValue()})
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Todos is currently an array sorted by a property of each todo object. I guess you're suggesting it'd be better to store as a map for searching it?

Comment: I ended up doing something a little different but this definitely led me to the solution so thank you! I'll upvote this\

Comment: Glad it helps, using array object is a similar logic. just need to use filter() instead of pluck()

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to iterate on todos in templates so I kept it as an array. I used ReplaySubjects to hold the todos so that getTodoById could make an return todo$ without triggering an event until the http call came back.

```
todoCache: Array<{todoId: string, todo$: ReplaySubject<Todo>}>

getAllRemote(): void { 
    this.http
    .post(URL_GET_TODOS)
    .pipe(
      tap((todo) => {

        this.addTodo(todo)
      })
    );
}

getOneRemote(todoId: string): void {
   this.http
      .post(URL_GET_ONE_TODO, { todoId })
      .pipe(
        tap((todo: Todo) => {
          this.addTodo([todo]);
        })
      );
}

getTodoById(todoId: string): ReplaySubject<Todo> { 
    const cachedTodo = this.todo.find(
      cachedTodo => cachedTodo.todoId === todoId
    );

    if (cachedTodo) {
      return cachedTodo.todo$;
    } else {
      this.chatUses.push({ todoId, todo$: new ReplaySubject(1) });
      this.apiGetChatUseByChatId(chatId, privateChat);
    }
}

addTodo(toAdd: Array<Todo>): void {

      for (let i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i += 1) {
        const index = this.todoCache.findIndex(
          entry => entry.todoId === toAdd[i].id
        );

        if (index === -1) {
          this.chatUses.push({
            todoId: toAdd[i].id,
            todo$: new ReplaySubject(1)
          });
          this.todoCache[this.todoCache.length - 1].todo$.next(toAdd[i]);
        } else {
          this.todo[index].todo$.next(toAdd[i]);
        }
      }
}
```